# Dynamically created label not visible on VBA userform

Tags: excel, vba

i have a Userform where I have a command button to view the reports(can be any file in a folder). If this folder has n files then on click event of the command button , 'n' labels needs to be created dynamically on the UserForm with file names displayed as the caption. Below code runs without error but the labels are not displayed on the UserForm.

```
Private Sub cmdViewReports_Click()

    Dim row_num As Long
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim src_path As String
    Dim dest_path As String
    Dim sub_folder As String
    Dim theLabel1 As msforms.Label
    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim my_files As Object
    Dim my_folder As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ctrl As Control

    'Check if the record is selected in listbox
    If Selected_List = 0 Then   

        MsgBox "No record is selected.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Upload Results"

        Exit Sub

    End If

    'Folder Name to be created as per the 3rd column value in the list 
    sub_folder = Me.lstDb.List(Me.lstDb.ListIndex, 3)

    sub_folder = Replace(sub_folder, "/", "_")

    dest_path = "C:\abc\xyz\Desktop\FV\" & sub_folder & "\"

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If Not fso.FolderExists(dest_path) Then

        MsgBox "No reports are loaded"

        Exit Sub

    End If

    Set my_folder = fso.GetFolder(dest_path)
    Set my_files = my_folder.Files

    i = 1

    For Each oFiles In my_files
        Set theLabel1 = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "File_name" & i, True)
                    With theLabel1
                        .Caption = oFiles.Name
                        .Left = 1038
                        .Width = 60
                        .Height = 12
                        .Top = 324 + inc
                        .TextAlign = 1
                        .BackColor = &HC0FFFF
                        .BackStyle = 0
                        .BorderStyle = 1
                        .BorderStyle = 0
                        '.Locked = True
                        .ForeColor = &H8000000D
                        .Font.Size = 9
                        .Font.Underline = True
                        .Visible = True
                    End With
                    MsgBox "Label" & i & " Created"
                inc = inc + 12
                i = i + 1

    Next   
End Sub
```

But when I run I am not able to see the labels. In this case I have 3 files in the folder so I should be 3 labels.

Also I want the labels to be hyperlinked, meaning that once I click the label the report/files should be displayed.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `.Left = 1038` seems pretty far to the left. Is your userform big enough to show that far left?

Comment: @JNevill yes the form is big enough for this :)

Comment: Have you stepped through the code?  Is the .Caption perhaps a null string?

Comment: Your code (The `setLabel1... ` and the bits in your `WITH` block) work fine for me. I changed .Left and .Top to `10` (for both) and changed the caption to a string literal and it created a label with blue underlined font.

Comment: @JNevill I have a frame in my form upon which the control are present. so when the controls were created , it was hidden behind the frame. Thanks guys

Comment: How do I add hyper link to this label ?

Comment: Hyperlinking a userform control is a whole other can of worms. I believe you need to create a `yourlabel.click()` event and do a `activeworkbook.FollowHyperlink(...)` which might be a little tricky to do dynamically. It may be worth asking a brand new question on here specifically about that including this code where the label is dynamically generated.

Comment: @JNevill ok .. I ll do that.. thanks